# Error while compiling srp-2.1.2 in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: security, ubuntu, passwords, single-responsibility-principle

I downloaded srp-2.1.2 source from http://srp.stanford.edu/source/srp-2.1.2.tar.gz.

Type: ./configure ---> everything ok

Type: make

At this point I keep getting the same error during the linking process. 
See the last lines below:

```
gcc  -O  -o telnet  authenc.o commands.o main.o network.o ring.o sys_bsd.o telnet.o terminal.o tn3270.o utilities.o Xauth.o XdmAuth.o fwdxutil.o parsedpy.o tlsutil.o ../libtelnet/libtelnet.a -lssl -L../../libsrp -lsrp -lcrypto  -ldl -lutil -lresolv -lnsl
telnet.o: In function `t_setupterm':
telnet.c:(.text+0x2030): undefined reference to `tgetent'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [telnet] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/srp-2.1.2/telnet/telnet'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/srp-2.1.2/telnet'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/srp-2.1.2/telnet'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
root@brrndvis05:~/srp-2.1.2#
```

It can not find any reference to 'tgetent'. I have no idea what that means. Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tgetent is provided by termcap. Install termcap, and it should work.